# How to match the PrometheusRule to the AlertmanagerConfig with Prometheus Operator

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager, prometheus-operator

I have multiple `prometheusRules(rule a, rule b)`, and each rule defined different exp to constraint the alert; then, I have different `AlertmanagerConfig`(one receiver is slack, then other one's receiver is `opsgenie`); How can we make a connection between rules and `alertmanagerconfig`? for example: if rule a is triggered, I want to send message to slack; if rule b is triggered, I want to send message to `opsgenie`.

Here is what I tried, however, that does not work. Did I miss something?

This is `prometheuisRule` file

```
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: PrometheusRule
metadata:
  labels:
    prometheus: service-prometheus
    role: alert-rules
    app: kube-prometheus-stack
    release: monitoring-prom
  name: rule_a
  namespace: monitoring
spec:
  groups:
    - name: rule_a_alert
      rules:
        - alert: usage_exceed
          expr: salesforce_api_usage > 100000
          labels:
            severity: urgent
```

This is `alertManagerConfig`

```
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1alpha1
kind: AlertmanagerConfig
metadata:
  labels:
    alertmanagerConfig: slack
  name: slack
  namespace: monitoring
  resourceVersion: "25842935"
  selfLink: /apis/monitoring.coreos.com/v1alpha1/namespaces/monitoring/alertmanagerconfigs/opsgenie-and-slack
  uid: fbb74924-5186-4929-b363-8c056e401921
spec:
  receivers:
  - name: slack-receiver
    slackConfigs:
    - apiURL:
        key: apiURL
        name: slack-config
  route:
    groupBy:
    - job
    groupInterval: 60s
    groupWait: 60s
    receiver: slack-receiver
    repeatInterval: 1m
    routes:
    - matchers:
      - name: job
        value: service_a
      receiver: slack-receiver
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to match on a label of the alert, in your case you're trying to match on the label `job` with the value `service_a` which doesn't exist.  You could either match on a label that does exist in the prometheuisRule file, eg `severity`, by changing the `match` in the alertManagerConfig file:

```
route:
  routes:
  - match:
      severity: urgent
    receiver: slack-receiver
```

or you could add another label to the prometheuisRule file:

```
spec:
  groups:
    - name: rule_a_alert
      rules:
        - alert: usage_exceed
          expr: salesforce_api_usage > 100000
          labels:
            severity: urgent
            job: service_a
```